# What is the most efficient way to get a pokemon with good IVs, nature, and ability?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I would like a step-by-step guide on how I would go about crafting a Pokemon that meets certain requirements.  How should I go about catching one?  How do I ensure it has the right nature and ability?  How do I check its IVs while also leaving it free to be EV trained in the future?  How can I ensure that certain important IVs are 31 and not 30 or lower?

For example, let's say I wanted to use a Mienshao that has 31 attack and speed IVs, with Regenerator and an Adamant nature.  I currently don't even have a Mienfoo.  Where do I begin, and what steps to I take?

I have multiple DSes and access to Black, White, and all 4th generation games, in case that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step would be acquiring a Mienfoo, which can be found in Route 14, Dragonspiral Tower, and Victory Road. The easiest way to breed for a specific nature is to find a Ditto with the nature you want the offspring to possess. From there, give the Ditto an Everstone and put the Mienfoo and the Ditto in the Day Care. The Everstone makes it so that the offspring has a 50% chance of inheriting the female parent's (or Ditto's) nature.

After this, you would just breed over and over until you get an offspring with 31 in either Attack or Speed. Give that baby Mienfoo a Power Bracer if the 31 is in Attack, or a Power Anklet if the 31 is in Speed (this forces that IV to be passed on). Repeat the process until you have a 31 in Attack and Speed, and hope that the ability is Regenerator.

<sub>I forget if you need to have a different parent in order to breed the offspring, or if you can just use the same Ditto again.</sub>

---

#### Checking IVs

The easiest way to check for IVs is to stockpile a lot of Rare Candies. Take note of the Pokémon's stats at each level, and input them into [this calculator](http://www.legendarypokemon.net/javacalc.html). The more levels you take note of, the more the calculator will be able to pinpoint your IV. (You can reset your game after testing each Pokémon so you can use the same Rare Candies over and over.)

Comment: How can I check whether the IV is 31 exactly?  Usually an IV calculator gives a range, especially with pokemon that are of lower level.

Comment: Ahh, forgot about that. I'll edit something in.

Comment: Stockpiling Rare Candies seems...difficult.  Seeing as they're one of the most expensive items in the Battle Subway.

Comment: Unfortunately Rare Candies and an IV Calculator are the only reliable way to check IVs. You could also battle with [high level Pickup Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pickup_(ability)#Pok.C3.A9mon_Black_and_White) in your party.

Comment: You can always reload your save after checking though.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant resetting after using the Rare Candies, not to keep obtaining them. Heh, that's pretty important.

Comment: Wow I'm not entirely sure how I didn't realize that, but that definitely makes getting enough Rare Candies a lot more feasible.  I'm going to try this out at some point in the near future.  It sounds mind-numbingly boring, but hopefully it's not too bad.

Comment: Yep, breeding for perfect IVs is extremely boring. Good luck getting that Mienshao! (Fake Out lead, am I right?)

Comment: @KevinY Yeah, exactly right.  Fake Out and U-Turn with Regenerator just struck a chord with me and I knew I had to have one.  Not sure what I'm using with it yet, but I'm just going to focus on this for a while.